# How to send a photo using telegram bot with js/jquery in html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, web, telegram-bot

Previously I have some code like this to send a message to the user

```
<button class="notif btn btn-success"
href="https://api.telegram.org/bot{{ config('app.token') }}/sendMessage?chat_id={{ $rp->report_idsender }}&text=Halo%20{{ $rp->sender_name }}%20permintaan%20anda%20dengan%20id%20{{ $rp->id }}%20sudah%20di%20close%20">Notif</button>
```

and I am using jquery & js to get URL from href and execute HTTPS post request it works perfectly for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".notif").unbind().click(function() {
var url = $(this).attr("href");
console.log(url);
var exe = $.post(url, function() {
alert('Success');
})
});
</script>
```

But now I want to send a photo to a group on Telegram with reply id and the codes looks like this:

```
<form method="POST"
action="https://api.telegram.org/bot{{ config('app.token') }}/sendPhoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="chat_id" value="{{ config('app.idgroup') }}" hidden />
<input type="text" name="reply_to_message_id" value="{{ $rp->msg_id }}" hidden />
<input type="text" name="allow_sending_without_reply" value="true" hidden />
<br />
<label for="caption"> Caption</label>
<input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="caption" />
<br />
<input type="file" name="photo" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="sendPhoto" />
</form>
```

The problem with this code is that after I submit the form it's opening a page that contains the JSON response whereas I just want to alert it as I did in the previous code.

[json response tab picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSWfr.png)

The question is, how can I send a photo with the form with telegram bot using js/jquery with reply id in the URL ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, but redirecting to page as set in `action`, you can use following code to prevent default submit button behavior and ajax to stay on the same page and display success message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data, status) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add this code on head section of your page.

Comment: thanks, it works fine! but can this function only works with a specific form?, because I got two forms with different submit button in the same page