# How to send a base64 photo using telegram bot with js/jquery in html form?

Tags: telegram

I want to send photo using telegram bot with js/jquery. I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612407/how-to-send-a-photo-using-telegram-bot-with-js-jquery-in-html-form) but it doesn't help with base64 photo. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try it.

```
            var imgBase64;
            urltoFile(imgBase64, 'a.jpeg')
                .then(function(file){
                    var data_tele = new FormData()
                    data_tele.append('photo',file);
                    data_tele.append('caption',"text");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.telegram.org/bot[token_bot]/sendphoto?chat_id=[chat_id]",
                        type: "POST",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data : data_tele,
                        success: function () {
                        }
                    })
                });
```

Comment: That's perfect and searches for exactly what I'm after. Thank you!