# Is there any ways to send a canvas item by using telegram api?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, telegram

Is there any possible ways to get my canvas by blob and send it using telegram api directly? I tried to convert the canvas into a url but telegram still cannot send it.

My system is about sending emergency message. When the alarm was triggered, the live graph will be send to a telegram group to notify the members. But what is troubling me is telegram only can send photo by using url or upload from local.

Below is my code example:

```
exportTelegramPNG(){

      const bot = {
        TOKEN:"telegram bot token",
        chatID:"telegram bot chatID",
      }

      const filename = this.state.stationRecord["StationName"]+'_'+this.state.currentDate;
      html2canvas(document.getElementById(this.chart2.current.chart.container.id)).then(function (canvas) {
      
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
          
          const newImg = document.createElement('img');
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          newImg.onload = () => {
          // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          };

          newImg.src = url;
          document.body.appendChild(newImg);

          fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${bot.TOKEN}/sendPhoto?chat_id=${bot.chatID}&photo=${newImg}`, {
            method:"GET"
            })
        });
        
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is the error log in console.

```
GET https://api.telegram.org/bot${bot.TOKEN}/sendPhoto?chat_id=${bot.chatID}&photo=[object%20HTMLImageElement] 400
```

Thank you for anyone who gives suggestion and helps.

Comment: how about `base64`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591436/how-to-send-a-base64-photo-using-telegram-bot-with-js-jquery-in-html-form

Comment: @GrafiCode my system is saving a live chart into an image, the live chart does'nt have url link and that is troubling me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code worked as below:

```
exportTelegramPNG(){

  const bot = {
    TOKEN: "Telegram bot token",
    chatID:"telegram bot chatID",
  }

  html2canvas(document.getElementById(this.chart2.current.chart.container.id)).then(function (canvas) {
  
  if (canvas) {
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {

      var caption = "Report"+'_'+this.state.currentDate;
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('photo', blob);
      formData.append('caption', caption);

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', `https://api.telegram.org/bot${bot.TOKEN}/sendPhoto?chat_id=${bot.chatID}`);
      request.send(formData);

    });
  }
});
```

}

Now my code will be able to get the data from live chart and send it to telegram group after I click the button.

Thanks to Graficode and Tural who help me and giving suggestion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram api  only accept either a url to an image or file/image upload. And you can use any blob data for sending without temporary file.

Comment: What if I want to direct send without download to my pc as it wasted my storage? I wanted to set the blob a url but i cant managed to do it.

Comment: You need to debug in console source before. If it will successfully before add to url. For debugging you try before add   some image real url . For example &photo=https://i.imgur.com/vB9dcs5.jpeg

Comment: I can send using image url. But if I convert my blob into url, it cannot send the image. Is localhost a problem? As my url contain localhost in it. For example, blob:http://localhost:3000/3d36f519-84b1-47c9-a2a7-86b9a587eca1

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code a bit to make it work for me.

```
function sendCanvas(obj) {
  const bot = {
    TOKEN: '5237151266:AAEqn8j4mRDnXxvcApmHJMzaXRsoIhvGKTY',
    chatID:'-1001719430367',
  }
  
  var canvas = document.getElementById(obj);
  if (canvas) {
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
      var caption = 'Summary Chart';
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('photo', blob);
      formData.append('caption', caption);
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot.TOKEN + '/sendPhoto?chat_id=' + bot.chatID);
      request.send(formData);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What does this add to the provided answer? The only difference seems to be that you use an existing canvas. But that is not what the question is about.